# Looking for patterns like 'mop' 'map', 'mXp' in the string, starting with lower case 'm' and ending with lower case 'p'

Tags: python

Hello I'm having trouble with this question. I've attempted to do it, however it seems like I'm doing something wrong.

Here's the question
'Look for patterns like 'mop' 'map', 'mXp' in the string, starting with lower case 'm' and ending with lower case 'p'. Return a string where for all such words, the middle letter is gone, so 'mopXmap' yields 'mpXmp'.'

Heres what i have so far

```
def mop_map(string):

        if len(string) <= 2:
        return string
    i = 0
    case = ""
    for index in range(0, len(string)):
        b = string[i]
        if i < len(string)-2:
            e = string[i+2]
            if b == "m" and e == "p":
                case = case + (b + e)
                i = i + 2
            else:
                case = case + b
                i = i + 1
        else:
            case = case + b
            i = i + 1
    return case


assert(mop_map('') == '')
assert(mop_map('abc') == 'abc')
assert(mop_map('mp') == 'mp')
assert(mop_map('mop') == 'mp')
assert(mop_map('map') == 'mp')
assert(mop_map('mipXmap') == 'mpXmp')
assert(mop_map('m pm p') == 'mpmp')
assert(mop_map('mmm1pm2p') == 'mmmpmp')
```

It passes until it hits "mop". I feel like I made it way more complicated than what it really needs to be. The answer should be simple right?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
"It fails" is not a specification.  What *does* the function return?  Why does it get that value, instead of what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

You've made heroic efforts to solve this problem. You're right to suspect there's an easier approach though. You can simply use regular expressions with the `re` package.

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile('m[a-zA-z]p')
results = re.findall(pattern, your_string)
```

`results` will contain a `list` of all non-overlapping strings that match your pattern.

Now you can print your words with the middle letter removed, if you wish.

```py
for result in results:
    final = result.replace(result[1], '')
    print(final)
```

Comment: Where are you removing the middle letter in the result?

Comment: You're right @Barmar, I realized that right after I submitted it.